# HTML Email : Images go beyond table width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am making HTML Emailer.

The issue that I am facing is, when I put 5th images in a single row then it expands table width, rather than going down in the center of new line.

```html
<table cellspacing="8" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; max-width: 500px !important; " width="500">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="text-align:center;height:60px; padding:10px;'.$border.'">
 <img src="http://www.hubilo.in/images_for_links/facebook.png" width="110">
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="text-align:center;height:60px; padding:10px;'.$border.'">
 <img src="http://www.hubilo.in/images_for_links/facebook.png" width="110">
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="text-align:center;height:60px; padding:10px;'.$border.'">
 <img src="http://www.hubilo.in/images_for_links/facebook.png" width="110">
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="text-align:center;height:60px; padding:10px;'.$border.'">
 <img src="http://www.hubilo.in/images_for_links/facebook.png" width="110">
    </td>            
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is , when i put 5th image then it should be down to the center of the new line. also it would be great , that the same output can be displayed in **Outlook**

Any help would be grateful.

Thank You.

Comment: As this is using `table` structure its difficult to achieve the desired effect, as an alternative use `div` to recreate table structure so that the desired effect can be achieved.

Comment: `div` is not supported by outlook. so have to use `table`

Comment: too bad because tables are designed not to wrap columns on new lines

Comment: there are 7 images. first 4 images in one line and rest are in new line. ohk.. so what if i remove any image from 1st line , then from the new line , the 1st image should be put to the last of the 1st line. just like Queue. that's why i need this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `display:inline-block` in your **td**.